# Data from mongodb when using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am using Spring boot with spring data. I have a mongodb and has the following record inside it:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5914281fae0fe519943367c7"), "_class" : "example.model.Customer", "username" : "test", "password" : "test", "message" : "test" }
```

I am trying to create a function in which it retrieves data from the record using their username and password. This is what I have so far:

```
public class findExistingUser {
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
public Customer findUser(String username, String password){
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("username").is(username).and("password").is(password));
    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Customer.class, "customer");
}
}
```

But for some reason I get a null pointer exception. When I debug, mongotemplate seems to be null.

Comment: Do you have mongoDB in your pom.xml?

Comment: @StimpsonCat Yes, I have `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Your class findExistingUser should be Spring bean (add @Component to declaration).

Comment: Please look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387496/how-to-autowire-mongotemplate-into-custom-type-converter

Comment: @BorLaze Thank you. Making the class a bean fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Below properties should be available in application.properties

`spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=app1`

And below dependecies should be available in pom

`org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.0.RELEASE
org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.1`

Comment: I have those settings configured. The database points to my databse I ave the records in. Still returning null

Comment: Is the `findExistingUser` class is annotated with @Componenet